# Please help with set identification from the picture of this part made car

Tags: set-identification

please help identify the set that this car is part of.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This belongs to [41034-1: Summer Caravan](https://brickset.com/sets/41034-1/Summer-Caravan)

[image]